# Visual Studio overwrites settings

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-registry, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

A chkdsk snafu rendered my computer unbootable, so IT gave me a new one.  Now I have to reinstall and reconfigure everything to my liking and Visual Studio 2012 gives me grief.

I managed to lift most of the data from the borked drive, including the registry hives, so I exported the relevant entries from the old HKCU hive and imported them into the current one (yes, I made a backup copy first)

Unfortunately, after I do this, the next time I start Visual Studio it overwrites the settings with some default values and I am back to where I started.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As luck would have it, right after I post the question, I find a solution.

Turns out VS exported the settings about a month ago for some reason.  I imported them back and things look much better now.